# В $_POST ничего не приходит из radiobuttons

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, почему ничего не приходит в $_POST['active'] из этих радиокнопок? Уже замучался, из остальных инпутов всё приходит, а с этими не могу разобраться.

```
<form method="post" id="forms" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="active" value="3" checked>
    <label>Да</label>
    <input type="radio" name="active" value="4">
    <label>Нет</label>
</form>
```

Comment: а кнопка для отправки пост-запроса где?

Comment: кнопка не важна, там в этой форме в реальности много инпутов, а не приходит именно из радиобаттонов в $_POST?

Comment: А как вы отправляете форму? Где кнопка submit ?
UPD: Вы точно не используете больше негде name=active ?
Можете скинуть код всей формы? т.к. по представленому коду все должно работать

Comment: кнопка не важна, там в этой форме в реальности много инпутов, а не приходит именно из радиобаттонов в $_POST?

Comment: Может вы уже используете name=active  ?

Comment: хотел написать свой обычный ответ, что в "active" в `$_POST['active']` и в `name="active"` буквы "а", "с" или "е" из разных алфавитoв, но проверив то, что в вопросе, увидел, что и там, и там ASCII < 128.

Comment: Покажите как вы на сервере проверяете данные

Comment: Я скопировал Вашу форму, добавил туда кнопку отправки, и вставил код вывода: `echo $_POST['active'];`. И у меня все работает.

Comment: Для вопросов используйте комментарии к вопросу

Comment: У меня не хватает рейтинга, чтобы задавать вопросы в комментариях к вопросу автора.

Comment: Ну типо было бы хорошо глянуть как данные принимаются, но ладно. Продолжим Битву Экстрасенсов

Answer (score 1):

И все-таки. Поменяйте на

```
$_POST['zzz']
```

и

```
name="zzz"
```